# Preprocessing the server response before passing it on to Axis

Tags: java, soap, axis, sourceforge

I'm in the very peculiar position of trying to access a SOAP service whose answers are wrapped in HTML. This is a bug with the service provider ( SourceForge ) , acknowledged for seven months, with no ETA so far. [Nitty-gritty details](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/1336).

If I can intercept the actual response before passing it on to Axis, I would be able to strip the HTML content, but I don't know how to do that. Any pointers ( as well as alternative solutions ) would be appreciated.

---

Update: Using Axis 1.4

Answer (score 1):

I would try to see if I can add a interceptor Stripping the HTML. They seem to use that for SOAP compression, have a look at:
http://www.thomas-bayer.com/soap-compression-howto.htm
Look at the client configuration part, maybe you can do something similar.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll look into providing a custom `transport` and see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add to the server side, a `ServletFilter` could be a solution.

If all you can change is on the client side, you can create a proxy servlet that receives the SOAP data, propagates it to the server and strips the result.

The actual stripping can be done using XSLT although that might be overkill if the wrapping html is constant.

Comment: I'm on the client side, but I don't think I understand your answer. What I do is invoke Axis on the client side then ( ... axis magic ... ) I get the actual response. I don't have any servlets in use.

Comment: Axis performs a servlet call, if you configure locally to call your proxy servlet, it can call the remote side and strip the response so that your Axis code receives the stripped resonse.